# C# LINQ Select rows from DataTable or DataView Where 2 Value Matches

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataview

I converted `CRMDataSetSent` into a `DataTable`/`DataView` containing the full list of records.

```
DataTable CRMDataSetSent_Dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(CRMDataSetSent_Dt, Variables.CRMDataSetSent);
DataView CRMDataSetSent_Dv = new DataView(CRMDataSetSent_Dt);
```

---

`distinct_Wo_Wop_Dt` stores distinct `msdyn_workorderid` + `msdyn_workorderproductid` pairs.

```
DataTable distinct_Wo_Wop_Dt= CRMDataSetSent_Dv.ToTable(true, "msdyn_workorderid", "msdyn_workorderproductid");
```

---

For each row in `distinct_Wo_Wop_Dt`, I need to fetch rows from `CRMDataSetSent_Dt`/`CRMDataSetSent_Dv` where both values match.

Right now I am doing it via `foreach` loop, which is not as efficient as I want it to be.

Is there a way to do this via `LINQ`?

Comment: Can you show your actual code? Can you explain `efficient`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but you seem to want [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join).

Comment: Use a where with an AND : DataTable results = CRMDataSetSent_Dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => (x.colA == 'abc') && (x.colB == '123')).CopyToDataTable().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood it correctly you want to remove duplicates according to 2 fields. You don't need the `DataView` temp storage at all which is not an efficient way to filter rows and it's not readable.

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
CRMDataSetSent_Dt = CRMDataSetSent_Dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => (msdyn_workorderid:r.Field<int>("msdyn_workorderid"),msdyn_workorderproductid:r.Field<int>("msdyn_workorderproductid")))
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

I have assumed that these fields are of type `int`, change it accordingly if necessary. You can also change the logic which row should be taken. I simply kept an arbitrary, the first. You could for example add an `OrderBy` to add a custom logic.